# How do i setup queue_classic background jobs on EC2 using the rubber gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2

How do i setup `queue_classic` background jobs on EC2 using the `rubber` gem?
I tried using foreman export but i'm not sure where to run it (app or web role?). 
My failed attempt is using http://blog.sosedoff.com/2011/07/24/foreman-capistrano-for-rails-3-applications/.

Should i be creating a new instance to run these jobs? (or a new role?)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

First create a Procfile with the queue_classic rake task (see http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html)

Then i added foreman to my host (make sure you have a procfile for that environment, ex: Procfile.production)

```
# Foreman tasks
namespace :foreman do
  desc 'Export the Procfile to Ubuntu upstart scripts'
  task :export, :roles => :queue do

    run "cd #{release_path} && bundle exec foreman export upstart /etc/init -f ./Procfile.#{Rubber.env} -a #{application} -u #{user} -l #{release_path}/log/foreman"
  end

  desc "Start the application services"
  task :start, :roles => :queue do

    rsudo "start #{application}"
  end

  desc "Stop the application services"

  task :stop, :roles => :queue do
    rsudo "stop #{application}"

  end

  desc "Restart the application services"
  task :restart, :roles => :queue do
    rsudo "stop #{application}; start #{application}"
    #run "sudo start #{application} || sudo restart #{application}"
  end
end
after "deploy:update", "foreman:export"    # Export foreman scripts
before "deploy:restart", "foreman:restart"   # Restart application scripts
after "deploy:stop", "foreman:stop"   # Restart application scripts
```